# Display issue - "Unknown Monitor"

Tags: nvidia, display

I cannot change display settings from the default 4:3 despite using a 16:9 display.

Display settings show "Unknown Display"

The only available option (default) is "1024x768 (4:3)" which results in a horizontally stretched 4:3 display on 16:9 monitors.

I've tried multiple monitors - Samsung and Viewsonic - 4 models using both VGA and HDMI connections.

***I have searched the forum for posts on similar issues and tried all the suggestions I can find to no avail.***

I am using an NVidia GeForce710 graphics card - NVidia drivers are installed.

I get the same results using the motherboard's integrated graphics.

I ran "xrandr" and "xrandr --listmonitors" - they both report "failed to get size of gamma for output default"

I cannot find a monitors.xml file at /home/.config/ (using terminal command ls -la or the files GUI)

I have checked the file /etc/default/grub
The relevant line is already GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" - without the "nomodeset"

Ubuntu is Ver 22.04.1 LTS 64bit on an Intel i5-3330.

Is the missing monitors.xml causing this grief?

All help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Peter Smerdon

Comment: I'd firstly check you have all security fixes and upgrades; you mention having 22.04.1 but a fully-upgraded 22.04 system has reported itself as 22.04.2 since before the ISO release date shown [here](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/).  You've also not said what 22.04 product, ie. desktop? server? or *flavor* as they have differences

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a desktop install. It's the standard version from ubuntu.com.

Comment: I have run all the prompted updates since I installed it many months ago. It has been exhibiting this behaviour since a few weeks after install (it was fine at install). 
What is the deal with the file monitors.xml.
Any idea why I don't have one, and can it be regenerated?

Comment: Your listed `monitors.xml` is an invalid address; it'll be in your `$HOME/.config/monitors.xml` or `/home/$USER/.config/monitors.xml` not your specified directory which excludes the $USER part of the address; but my system (*a later release*) doesn't have any nvidia kernel modules which can change what is used...  (*you state you have nvidia kernel modules installed, but not which was installed & I don't know your card*)  FYI: You should have upgraded to 22.04.2 on or around 24-26 Feb 2023 if not before (*or whenever you turned on machine around or after those dates*).

Comment: Thanks.
I think (hope) we are talking about the same directory for monitors.xml. I'm not seeped in the correct Linux terminology, so probably wrote it wrongly. In the location shown in the prompt where I first land when I open the Terminal ("machine-name:~$"), and also when I open the "Home" folder in the Files GUI (they are both the same spot), there is a .config directory. There is no file "monitors.xml" in that directory.

Comment: Regarding the NVIDIA drivers, 
Software&Updates reports 

"NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
This device is using the recommended drivers
Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary, tested)"

Comment: FYI:  The directory `~` is shorthand for $HOME or `/home/$USER/` which is `/home/guiverc/` for myself...  (ie. my username or $USER is "guiverc").  The directory `/home/` contains a number of directories; each used by user accounts; my username is 'guiverc' thus my home directory is `/home/guiverc/` (ie. subdirectory inside `/home`). As I'm not very familiar with nvidia & its effects (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/nvidia-driver-470) you're probably best waiting for advice from others..

Comment: Thanks for your advice and efforts.
:-)

Peter Smerdon.

Comment: xrandr --listmonitors

Answer (score 0):

got this from a Copilot (GPT 4)
and to my surprise, it worked:

sudo su

add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y

apt update

apt upgrade

ubuntu-drivers devices

apt install nvidia-driver-470-server

reboot